# How to select a portion of an image, crop, and save it using Swift?

Tags: ios, image, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, crop

I am trying to create an iOS app using Swift to capture images and let the user save a selected portion of the image. In many cam based apps, I noticed that a rectangular frame is offered to let the users choose the desired portion. This involves either sliding the edges of the rectangle or moving the corners to fit the required area.

Could you please guide me on how to implement that moveable rectangle and how to save only that piece of the image?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found one more solution. This time it is in Swift. The solution looks elegant and the code relative to other such solutions is written in fewer number of lines.

Here it is..
https://github.com/DuncanMC/CropImg
Thanks to Duncan Champney for making his work available on github.

Comment: This has not been updated for Xcode 8 / Swift 3 so it does not work.

Answer (score 39):

**Using Swift 3**

Image cropping can be done using **CGImages** from **CoreGraphics**.

Get the CGImage version of a UIImage like this:

```
// cgImage is an attribute of UIImage
let cgImage = image.cgImage
```

CGImage objects have a method ***cropping(to: CGRect)*** that does the cropping:

```
let croppedCGImage: CGImage = cgImage.cropping(to: toRect)
```

Finally, convert back from **CGImage** to **UIImage**:

```
let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage)
```

**Example function:**

```
func cropImage(image: UIImage, toRect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
    // Cropping is available trhough CGGraphics
    let cgImage :CGImage! = image.cgImage
    let croppedCGImage: CGImage! = cgImage.cropping(to: toRect)

    return UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage)
}
```

The CGRect attribute of cropping defines the 'crop rectangle' inside the image that will be cropped.

Comment: why is this answer not marked as the right one? Does this code work?

Comment: Should be proper answer, mainly due to native code and no third party libs

Comment: What we got to write instead of the argument CGRect ? I'm a little bit confused

Comment: Request an example of use w/ original and cropped images ... I'm getting something, but the result is odd (rotated, etc.).

Comment: is there anything similar , to crop specific rect of a video and play that rect in a separate layer

Answer (score 7):

https://github.com/myang-git/iOS-Image-Crop-View does something like what you are looking for..

Hope this helps.

Comment: The solution you offered precisely suits my requirement, however it is in Objective-C, I will try either to code it in Swift or prepare a bridging header file. Thanks Subbu you saved my precious time. I sincerely appreciate Ming Yang, who posted this solution on github.

Comment: is there a swift version of this solution?

Comment: Is swift version available on iOS-Image-Crop-View?

Answer (score 0):

If you getting issue like rotating 90 after cropping image try this.
Store the original image scale and orientation property for later Use

```
let imgOrientation = image?.imageOrientation
let imgScale = image?.scale
```

Get the CGImage from UIImage:

```
let cgImage = image.cgImage
```

Pass the cropArea(CGRect) area you want to crop (incase you are using imageView.image you have find the scale and do maths to find cgRect) adding that code below if needed

```
let croppedCGImage = cgImage.cropping(to: cropArea)
let coreImage = CIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage!)
```

Need context for rendering image (its a heavy process do check [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext](http://CIContext) if you are doing multiple times ) using this you can set the scale and orientation we created in first line so image don't rotate 90

```
let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(coreImage, from: coreImage.extent)
let finalImage = UIImage(cgImage:filteredImageRef!, scale:imgScale!, orientation:imgOrientation!)
imageView.image = finalImage
```

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for an answer for iOS 13, Swift 5, and here comes the savior library: [CropViewController](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController).

It has almost every feature you can dream of: cropping at any aspect ratio, image rotation, reset to original image, translucent background. Also it is easy to install (Cocoapod, Carthage) and very easy to use. Remember to check out their demo sample app included in the repo.