# How make photo to scale and cut like in Skype?

Tags: swift, swift2

When i want change my profile photo in Skype i have a screen

[image]

When i click Take Photo my next screen is

[image]

and i can scale this pic to make them bigger

[image]

after i tap Use Photo my pic is cut and i see in the circle

[image]

I know how to take photo and paste in my ImageView but how they create this template area which will be cut the picture and how cut it ? Any hint please

Comment: I think is duplicate question with [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254435/how-to-select-a-portion-of-an-image-crop-and-save-it-using-swift)