# How do I perform Face Detection in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

Im using the following code to detect a face from an image.

```
let userDirectory = FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
let desktopDirectory = userDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Desktop")
let pictureUrl = desktopDirectory.appendingPathComponent("test").appendingPathExtension("jpg")

let image = CIImage(contentsOf: pictureUrl)   
let faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])
let faces = faceDetector?.features(in: image!) as! [CIFaceFeature]
print("Number of faces: \(faces.count)")
```

How can I detect a face and save it to an NSImage?

Comment: So, `CIFeature` has a `bounds` property, which defines the bounding rectangle of what was found. So the question becomes "how do you copy a portion of an image"? To which [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254435/how-to-select-a-portion-of-an-image-crop-and-save-it-using-swift) might shed some light (personally I like the top voted answer) and then you could have a look at [How to save a UIImage to a file using UIImagePNGRepresentation](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-save-a-uiimage-to-a-file-using-uiimagepngrepresentation)

Comment: OSX has no UIwhatever. He also needs to convert from NSImage to CIImage and back to NSImage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Xcode 9 • Swift 4**

```
extension NSImage {
    var ciImage: CIImage? {
        guard let data = tiffRepresentation else { return nil }
        return CIImage(data: data)
    }
    var faces: [NSImage] {
        guard let ciImage = ciImage else { return [] }
        return (CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])?
            .features(in: ciImage) as? [CIFaceFeature])?
            .map {
                let ciimage = ciImage.cropped(to: $0.bounds)  // Swift 3 use cropping(to:)
                let imageRep = NSCIImageRep(ciImage: ciimage)
                let nsImage = NSImage(size: imageRep.size)
                nsImage.addRepresentation(imageRep)
            return nsImage
        }  ?? []
    }
}
```

---

Testing

```
let image = NSImage(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!)!
let faces = image.faces
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. How can I adjust the size of the Crop window? i.e.: Get the detected face rectangle , increase the size of the rectangle and crop that portion.. Does changing `$0.bounds` with a custom rectangle help.. Please advice.

Comment: @techno the answer is at the iOS question which I linked when I closed your other question. You can use `bounds.insetBy(dx: -10, dy: -10)`

Comment: Thanks a lot... :)

Comment: Using `cropping.to` and `bounds.insetBy` produces incorrect results when drawing a text over detected bitmap.

Comment: @techno this has nothing to do with that code. Sorry buddy but I don’t have time for that question now.

Comment: Try redrawing your image after applying the inset. this is iOS but should be really similar for macOS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098390/swift-png-image-being-saved-with-incorrect-orientation/42098812#42098812

Comment: Thanks for replying even when you are Busy.Sorry,I have been pestering you because I have been stuck with this piece of code for few days.Tried everything to sort out the issue, but nothing works and no one is able to help.Should I redraw the NSImage.. can you point me to some resource ..

Comment: @techno  I haven’t coded for macOS for more than 2 years. Try googling it. It is easier than searching with SO search field

Comment: I have found this answer by you https://stackoverflow.com/a/42098812/848968 But this applies for `ios`..

Comment: @techno kkkk this is my own that I posted above. use it as a reference to translate to macOS

Comment: okay.. thanks ...I think I should redraw the nsimage after this `let imageRep = NSCIImageRep(ciImage: ciimage)
                let nsImage = NSImage(size: imageRep.size)
                nsImage.addRepresentation(imageRep)` ..

Comment: Tried Redrawing - `nsImage.lockFocus()
                nsImage.draw(in: NSRect(origin: NSZeroPoint, size: nsImage.size))
                nsImage.unlockFocus()
`  It does not fix the issue... it seems the the whole image is shifted..

Comment: Original Image https://imgur.com/a/b5ni7 ... Saved Image after Face Detection and Drawing Text https://imgur.com/a/P86je .. Text is Drawn using  this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/46844728/848968 ... Please take a look if your time permits...Thanks